# gulp with less and browser-sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, less, browser-sync

I am just starting with gulp and following this example:
[css tricks - Gulp for Beginners](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/)

```
   'gulp less'  works fine
   'gulp browser-sync' loads index.html into chrome
```

but when I run the 'watch' command, it only runs 'browser-sync.  Following in the debugger shows it does not return from `browserSync.init`

What am I missing?

`
                var gulp = require( 'gulp' ),
                      less = require( 'gulp-less' ),
                      browserSync = require( 'browser-sync' ).create()
                      ;

```
            gulp.task( 'less', _=>{
                return gulp.src( './public/content/*.less' )
                              .pipe( less( { paths: ['public/content'] } ) )
                              .pipe( gulp.dest( './public/content' ) )
                              .pipe( browserSync.reload( { stream: true } ) )
                      ;
            } );

            gulp.task( 'browser-sync', _=>{
                browserSync.init( { server: { baseDir: './public' } } );
            } );

            gulp.task( 'watch', ['browser-sync'], _=>{
                gulp.watch( 'public/content/*.less', ['less'] );
            } );
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

```
    `return browserSync`
```

did the trick.  This is not the way the demo was written.